# Unable to mount ext4 pendrive in Ubuntu

Tags: usb, 20.04, ext4

I have formatted the pen drive in ext 4 version. And now the system is unable to mount it. I think I have ejected it before UN-mounting it. Please help

Comment: You can check the filesystem with the *Disk Management* tool called "**Disks**". If it cannot fix the problem, you may have to reformat the disk.

Comment: [This link](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986) can help you repair the file system -- Summary: Boot from another file system, check that the target file system is unmounted and run `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/sdxn` where x is the linux drive letter and n is the partition number.

Comment: Pull the pen-drive off and insert it again.

Comment: Every time I insert the pen-drive it say "unable to access - an operation is already pending". While checking the disk it not showing any option to format the pen-drive.

Comment: Hi sudodus, it says e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

Comment: nohup.out file is created in files folder and it says "Gdk-Message: 20:40:55.248: nm-applet: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1."